# series ratio test

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

```
 Let`s say we want to compute $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $$ and we have two conditions:
```

1) there exists $$kn$$ such that the subsequence $$a_(kn) = 0$$
2) the modulus of the limit of the ratio of 2 consecutive non-zero terms is less than 1.
Can we still apply the ratio test?

( i thought that maybe we can bound our series by $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b*q^n $$, but as we can not write $$a_n <q^n$$, i m stuck.)
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Consider the sequence

$$a_{3n} = 2, a_{3n+1} = 1, a_{3n+2}=0$$
that is,
$$a=[2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, ...]$$

If you apply the ratio-test, as you said, only for consecutive non-zero terms, you will only be considering the ratios

$$\frac{a_{3n+1}}{a_{3n}} = \frac{1}{2} < 1$$

but the series isn't convergent.

## However

You may still use the ratio test, just not only for *consecutive* non-zero terms, but in general for all non-zero terms.

Let's say there's a series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$$

with infinite number of non-zero terms.

For all $k\geq 0$, define $b_k$ as the $k$'th non-zero element in the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$.

Since we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$$

then you can apply the ratio test to the second series and conclude the results for the first one.